# Display resultset from two different db servers into one report in SSRS with parameter selection

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've two tables in two db servers with same structure. I'm preparing a SSRS report with tablename & joining date as parameter selection. If I select table1 [dropdown] and joiningdate from/to date filter then table1 data will display in SSRS report and if I select table2 then it should display table2 data.

table1
cols: eid, ename, eno, joiningdate
table2
cols: eid, ename, eno, joiningdate

N.B:
there should be one dataset and one report

Comment: Do you have a question or a problem you'd like help with?  This looks like you're asking someone to just build the report for you.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have 2 datasets one from each server. Then have 2 tablix for the corresponding dataset. Depending on the parameter selected, you show the corresponding tablix and hide the other one..

If your `@source` paramameter had a value of 1 (for source one) and 2 (for source 2)

You could go one step further and pass that to your query.. like for dataset1 you can include `where @source = 1` and your dataset2 says `where @source = 2`

This would prevent the code from running unnecessarily on the server that it is not intended for.. makes sense?

Comment: I'm trying to maintain a single dataset with dynamic sql queries but not able to do that. And I want to show in a single tablix based on the parameter selection.

Comment: do you have a linked server setup between the two servers so you can run query from only one server? In which case.. you can simply do a union all between the desired tables

Answer (score 0):

If you have the 2nd server linked from the first server then you can just do something like this from the first server ..

```
IF @Server = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT eid, ename, eno, joiningdate FROM table1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT eid, ename, eno, joiningdate FROM [MyLinkedServerName].[myDatabaseName].[mySchemaName].[table1]
    END
```

... where `@Server` is the parameter name passed in from SSRS